# Rename files with Parent Directory Name

Tags: command-line

I want to rename file name with it’s parent folder name, adding folder name before file name.

Folder Structure:

1

```
A.jpg
B.jpg
C.jpg
```

2

```
A.jpg
B.jpg
C.jpg
```

Expected results:

1

```
1A.jpg
1B.jpg
1C.jpg
```

2

```
2A.jpg
2B.jpg
2C.jpg
```

How can this be done with Unix?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

In the `zsh` shell (available on most Unices since 1991, though `zmv` was *only* added in 2000):

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(*)/(*.jpg)' '$1/$1$2'
```

Comment: It renamed the files but put all files in folder 1. Can it keep files in their individual folders after renaming?

Comment: My mistake. Actually is does keep them in folders. This is exactly what I needed. Thank You!